# getting mapMappableContainerException while calling the rst service from postman

Tags: web-services, rest, maven, jersey, spring-restcontroller

com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.Mybean.class not present

Getting error.I'm using jersey rest api to run the existing java class
using maven,jersey.

Answer (score 0):

Check the BuildPath and add proper jar in the Project.
check the classpath for the jars.